# Raleigh Twenty forks too narrow to accept 93mm hub

Tags: fork, hub, steel

93mm hubs are standard size for the R20s but on this particular bike there isn't enough clearance between the fork ends to get a wheel in (I'm using an original R20 wheel as a replacement so it's definitely the correct size).

I know that the bike had an "accident" at some point that trashed the front wheel but I don't have any other details about what exactly happened to it, so I'm thinking the front might have been run over by a car or something and that crushed the forks somewhat. They look structurally sound, but would it be a bad idea to cold-set them and draw them apart a bit, or am I possibly missing something in the way I'm trying to replace the wheel? I have no experience with vintage bikes so some guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How bad is it?  If it's only a couple of mm then just manually spread the fork slightly as you install the wheel.

(Also make sure that no unnecessary washers have been added to the axle.)

Comment: It's about 3mm so not completely totalled but some distance from being negligible. The forks are also slightly out of alignment front-to-back (i.e. one is pushed a little forward) but the lateral positioning shouldn't be too bad once secured to the axle. I'm replacing the forks anyway, but want to be reasonably sure that the current stock ones aren't going to snap and kill me in the interim from being stressed too much.